# Find an order-embedding of $S_3\times{\bf2}\times{\bf2}$ into ${\mathbb Z}^4$

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, posets, linear-orders

A function $f:P\to Q$ from a poset $(P,\le_P)$ to a poset $(Q,\le_Q)$ is an *order-embedding* if, for all $p,p'\in P$, $p\le_P p'$ if and only if $f(p)\le_Q f(p')$.

We partially order the Cartesian product $P\times Q$ of posets $(P,\le_P)$ and $(Q,\le_Q)$ as follows: for $(p,q),(p',q')\in P\times Q$, $(p,q)\le_{P\times Q}(p',q')$ if $p\le_P p'$ and $q\le_Q q'$.  Similarly, we can define the product of more than two posets.

A *chain* is a poset $(C,\le)$ that is totally ordered: that is, for all $c,c'\in C$, either $c\le c'$ or $c'\le c$.  For $n\in\mathbb N$, we denote the $n$-element chain by $\bf n$; its elements are $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$.

The *dimension* of a poset $P$ is the smallest number of chains into the product of which we can order-embed $P$.

Consider the poset $S_3:=({\bf 2}\times{\bf 2}\times{\bf 2})\setminus\{(0,0,0),(1,1,1)\}$.  It is called the *standard poset of dimension 3*.

The poset $S_3\times{\bf 2}$ is shown in the figure below. The colors of the lines are merely for ease of reading.

[image]

If you put lines between the "corresponding" elements of the two parts of the diagram below, you will have $S_3\times{\bf 2}\times{\bf 2}$.

[image]

Find an order-embedding of $S_3\times{\bf 2}\times{\bf 2}$ into a product of 4 chains.

According to the middle of page 80 of Lin ("The dimension of the Cartesian product of posets," *Discrete Mathematics* **88** (1991), 79-92), there should be one.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the paper even claims the dimension to be 3, not 4…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We present an embedding into $\mathbb Z^3$. It is symmetric with respect to the premutation of the coordinates in $S_3$, so it suffices to show the images of the following elements $((x,y,z),a,b)\in S_3\times \mathbf 2\times \mathbf 2$:

$((1,0,0),a,b)\mapsto (5,0,0)+a(2,0,0)+b(0,1,1)$;

$((1,1,0),a,b)\mapsto (5,5,0) +a(2,2,0)+b(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Thank you.  I have a further question: Are there integers $a,b,k\ge2$ such that $S_3\times{\bf2}\times{\bf k}$ can be order-embedded into ${\bf a}\times{\bf b}\times{\bf k}$?

Comment: You may ask this as a separate question.

Comment: I have done so: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454521/find-an-order-embedding-of-s-3-times-bf2-times-bf-k-into-a-product-of-3